# Images broken while trying to display it from database in django

Tags: python, django

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT='/home/akanksha/bookepdia/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/akanksha/bookepdia/templates',)
```

Model.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/akanksha/bookepdia/media/images/')
```

Url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^$', 'bookepdia.views.home', name='home'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    photos = Image.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('display.html', {'photos' : photos})
```

display.html

```
<html>
<h3>Images of books</h3>
<img src="/media/images/image_name" />
{% for p in photos %}
    <img src="{{p.photo.url}}" />
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Now,my problem is when I have added /media/images/image_name the image is displayed but when I use {{p.photo.url}} the image is displayed as broken icon.
I found out it is taking the path as /home/akanksha/bookepdia/media/images/image_name.
Now,I want to edit this for every url so that it works as /media/images/image_name.

Comment: In the generated display.html, what do you see in place of the `{{p.photo.url}}`? Is it `/home/akanksha/bookepdia/media/images/<something>`?

Comment: yes,exactly that is what I see

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't give absolute path into `upload_to` in `ImageField`, it should be path relative to your MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: It does not matter I suppose in either case it behaves the same.

Comment: You must upload new image, images uploaded with old `upload_to` path won't be affected by that change - that means URL will be still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`upload_to` attribute of ImageField is not absolute path, it is relative to `MEDIA_ROOT` setting.

In your case it should be like this:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

> **FileField.upload_to**
>
> A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.

Comment: I tried after making changes but still it is displaying the image as broken icon

Comment: and what is `{p.photo.url}` now?

Comment: Same as earlier /home/akanksha/bookepdia/media/images/image_name

Comment: Do you upload new image? Images that have been uploaded before `upload_to` changed has not been affected

Comment: I didn't upload any new image.No change in images that have been uploaded before upload_to changed.

Comment: Ilya Tikhonov it is working correctly for new images I upload .Thank you.